# Pull field from master table where two child tables have matching data

Tags: sql

I have a 3 tables.

`Table ='FileName', Field inside FileName = 'ID'`

Child Table 'Department A' related to 'FileName'by 'ID', Field inside `Department A = 'LastNameA'`

Child Table 'Department B' related to 'FileName' by 'ID', Field inside`Department B = 'LastNameB'`

Is it possible to select all 'ID' records from the 'FileName' table `WHERE'Department A::LastNameA' = 'Department B::LastNameB'`?

If so, how would I write this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Questions is a bit unclear on which fields are in which table but choose which version works for you.

```
SELECT ID
FROM FileName fn
INNER JOIN DepartmentA da ON fn.ID = da.LastNameA
INNER JOIN DepartmentB db ON fn.ID = db.LastNameB
WHERE da.LastNameA = db.LastNameB
```

Or

```
SELECT ID
FROM FileName fn
INNER JOIN DepartmentA da ON fn.ID = da.ID
INNER JOIN DepartmentB db ON fn.ID = db.ID
WHERE da.LastNameA = db.LastNameB
```

Comment: shouldn't join by on ID? fn.ID = da.ID

Comment: Yeh possibly, question isn't the most clearest, i have provided both